# How to copy values in a row to empty rows below lots of times?

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

In Google sheets, I have rows set up like this:

```
Row1 - Header,
Row2 - Value1,
Row3 - Empty,
Row4 - Empty,
Row5 - Value2,
Row6 - Empty,
Row7 - Empty,
Row8 - Value3,
...
```

This goes on for hundreds of rows. I need to copy the value into the two empty rows below it.

For example,

```
copy Value1 into rows 3 and 4, Value2 into rows 6 and 7
```

and so on.

Does anyone know how I could do this using a for loop?

So far I have this:

```
function copyRowsDown() {

//Add spreadsheet URL
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(URL); 

//Add exact name of sheet
  var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheetName); 

  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();

  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();

  for (var i = 2; i <= numRows + 3; i += 3) {
//NEED THIS BIT           
    }
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've coded a sample loop in the console to show how this might be done. I return an array with the blank values "filled in" in the method I have below based on an iteration through the column values.

In your case, instead of pushing into the array, you would use the google sheets command to edit the column, or you could iterate through the generated array and replace each of the blank columns in the row with the corresponding value at the index in the generated array.

```
function fillColumn(array){
for (let i =1; i<array.length; i+=3){
    let new_arr =[]
    let to_fill = new Array(3).fill(array[i])
    new_arr.push(...to_fill);


}
return new_arr
}
```

I've included a picture of how the function works below.

Let me know if this is what you need!

[image: demo]